# Why are Vishnu and Narayana mentioned as separate deities in Tantra?

Tags: vishnu, tantra

According to he Paschima-Aamnaya of Tantra, Krishna, Gopala, Narayana, and Vishnu are different deities (Sastramulak Bharatiya Shaktisadhana,  Upendrakumar Das, RMIC, page 1049).

Can anybody provide the dhyana-mantras of Vishnu and Narayana from this scripture so that the differece between them becomes clear? In Bengal, Sri Vishnu is worshipped by the dhyana-mantra of Narayana seated in the Savitri-mandala and so we do not treat theses two deities differently by the way.